# How to define \marginpar when using it in two custom commands?

Tags: marginpar, report, todonotes

How can I define `\marginpar` options in custom commands so it does not affect other commands using `\marginpar`?

Here is what I have tried, but the problem still persists:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=159.2mm,top=25.4mm,bottom=25.4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%Paragraph number
\newcounter{parnum}
\newcommand{\n}{ 
    \refstepcounter{parnum}\leavevmode 
    \marginpar[\scriptsize\S\theparnum\hfill]{\scriptsize\hfill\centering\S\theparnum}
    \marginparwidth=15pt
    \marginparsep=15pt
    }

%Todonotes
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage[
    colorinlistoftodos,
    prependcaption,
    textsize=scriptsize,
    textwidth=2.5cm]{todonotes}
% Defining custom todo
\newcommand{\note}[1]{
    \todo[linecolor=orange,backgroundcolor=orange!25,bordercolor=orange]{#1}
    \marginparwidth=2.5cm
    \marginparsep=0.4cm
    }

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}

\n \blindtext %Without todonotes

\n \blindtext\note{Just a todo test!}

\n \blindtext\note{Another todo test!}

\newpage %for behaviour both in right and left side
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\n \blindtext %Without todonotes

\n \blindtext\note{Just a todo test!}

\n \blindtext\note{Another todo test!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks for the help and attention!